# Java - Button Action Questions

Tags: java, swing, button, jbutton

I have a series of JButtons that I have added to a JPanel. They are to type in the numbers 1 to 10, but I don't really know how to do this. I have a blank string which is displayed which I want the numbers added to when clicked. But I don't know if I should have a different event for each button or even how this should be properly achieved! Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: you mean a calculator? There are many tutorials on it:   http://www.beginner-java-tutorial.com/java-swing-calculator.html or go onto the oracle website because I know they have a tutorial on this.

Comment: *"Java - Button Action Questions"*  You've described a problem and how you can't do it, but have so far not asked a question (let alone a specific, answerable question).

Comment: You don't need a different event for each button. Give all the buttons the same ActionListener and get the button's text by calling `getActionCommand()` on the ActionEvent object passed into the actionPerformed method and then use that String in any way you see fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by taking a look at [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jEXxaPQ_fQo) video tutorial.

If you just want to print a number on the screen, then, you could re-use the same event handler, however, you might have some problems down the line should you require any changes, so I would recommend that you use different handlers which all call the same method and pass a string to it, which is the string that you would like to see displayed on the screen. This method would then render whatever you would like to put on your screen.

Answer (score 0):

Have your current class implement the **ActionListener** interface.

For the JButton objects, call the method
JButton.**addActionListener(this);**

Also, set an action command for each JButton with:
JButton.**setActionCommand("the command");**

Finally, add a method **actionPerformed()** in your class, *(this gets called everytime an action occurs)*. It should look like this:

```
private void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

String cmd = event.getActionCommand();

if (cmd.equals("a command")){

//.. do something

}

if (cmd.equals("another command")){

//..do something else

}

//... and the code goes on
}
```